# Is there an R function to join tables, counting the shared values in columns against a selected variable?

Tags: r

I have two tables, one with Trip IDs and Road Link IDs, and another with Road Link IDs.
I need to create a table with the Trip IDs as the first column (no duplicates), and the Road link IDs as columns. In the body of the table there is count of the Road link IDs against each trip ID.

I'm looking for a solution in R.
Excel power query seems to perform something similar with a Table.NestedJoin( ,JoinKind.Inner) function if that helps.

Comment: why do you need to use the second table for this?  just reshaping the first one aught to do it?

Comment: Do you have an example of the data?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your second table having only the road column does not add any information, making it unnecessary.
Try sth. like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data1 <- tribble(
  ~trip, ~road,
  1, "A",
  1, "A",
  2, "B",
  3, "B"
)

data1 %>%
  count(trip, road) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = road, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>    trip     A     B
#>   <dbl> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     2     0
#> 2     2     0     1
#> 3     3     0     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! The second table contains a subset of Road link IDs. I need a count of the number of times one of the trips traverse one of those Road links (from the subset). So I'm looking for a table with the Road trips links (from the second table) as column headers, and each row is a Trip ID which traverses one of those Road links (from the subset).

Comment: Please provide examples for the two input tables and for the desired output table using R function `dput`. Then, elaborate in your question why the second table is needed and how it should be used to filter rows of the other table (e.g. we only want to count roads present in the second table).